# What would the firmware to control Shift1 system (for 1-pin shift register operation) look like?

Tags: arduino, multiplexer, shift-register

This is a follow on question from [this answer by Spehro Pefhany](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/104987/29792), in which he explains to us how to use 74HC595 serial shift registers with only one digital output pin. Below's the picture he posted.

[image: Shift1 system by Roman Black]

Out of curiosity, and also to evaluate whether I would be able to control a shift register myself, my questions are:

**1. How complicated is it to control shift registers in this way with a MCU, in C, for example?**

**2. How would the firmware that controls this shift register look like?**

**3. Are there Arduino libraries to help us handle that (or for other platforms as well)?**

I have no idea on how to start.

Comment: The diagram is quite explicit: you set the pin low for a specific amount of time, make it high again, wait for a minimum time, repeat for all bits, repeat for latch pulse. BTW did you note that you loose one output pin?

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen - yes, it is explicit, but I'm struggling to design the code that would just do that. I understand that I would have to use a timer and (as a Software Engineer) would probably like to abstract the high/low action behind a function like Arduino's `shiftOut`.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen - and yes, I understand that I would have to use one pin to drive this, but then I would save the other two that I usually waste controlling clock and latch. Or is there another pin being used elsewhere?

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen - I would definitely try this out in the next few days, so I'll post my attempt at a code that drives this as an answer. It's my homework - the upfront research that I have not done, yet.

Comment: I recall that you use an Arduino? There is surely some library that has a delay_us() call or something similar!

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen There is a `delayMicroseconds` function, but it only has a minimum delay time of 2μs, which is too long for the first pulse.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen - Yes, it's `delayMicroseconds()`. But I wanted to use a timer overflow interrupt so that the main loop can do other things.

Comment: @Ricardo I read [here](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=11488) (section: _How long does it take to execute an ISR_) that the interrupt latency on the Arduino is in the region of 2.625μs, which would be too long.

Comment: @Shaktal - So it means so far that this arrangement can't be driven by a 16MHz Arduino? That's too bad!

Comment: @Ricardo I think it can be; you'd just have to `nop` for 16 cycles in the main `loop` before calling `digitalWrite`, you wouldn't be able to use an interrupt

Comment: If you don't like the timings I think you could use 22nF capacitors and multiply all times by 10. But Ricardo, you seem to think that this circuit is the best invention since sliced bread. It is a nifty toy. I don't think any professional would include it in a serious design. Use plain 595, or an I2C chip like the MCP23017 (there must be arduino libraries for both).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only a rough answer because there are areas I'm not sure of, so I'd appreciate it if anyone could point out mistakes. I assume one of your issues is that the `delay` function only allows for a resolution of milliseconds and the `delayMicroseconds` function only has a minimum delay time of 2μs. However, the [ATmega32U4](http://www.atmel.com/devices/atmega32u4.aspx) on the Arduino Micro (and others as well) has a clock speed of 16MHz, we can therefore calculate the time between cycles:

$$\Delta t = \frac{1}{16\text{ MHz}}=0.0625\: \mu\text{s}$$

Therefore, we can calculate how many clock cycles need to elapse before changing the output from `HIGH` to `LOW` and back again. We want a delay of 1μs and therefore we calculate:

$$n=\frac{1}{0.0625}=16$$

Where n is the number of clock cycles. We therefore want the CPU to wait for 16 cycles, we can achieve this with some inline assembly:

```
__asm__("nop\n\t"/*14 more of these*/"nop\n\t");
```

However, I haven't taken into account the number of clock cycles `digitalWrite` requires before changing the output pin voltage, so you would need to look into that too.

As I said, this is just a sketch answer, so I'd appreciate validity checks and suggestions/criticisms; I'm quite new to this!